# How to check if the given row matches one of the rows of a table?

Tags: syntax, conditional

Consider some table

```
tabb = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {5, 4}]
```

and a row

```
row = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 4]
```

How to check if `row` matches with at least one row of `tabb`?

Comment: How about using SameQ? as in `SameQ[row,#]&/@tabb`  screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXZDY.png)  This shows second row matched. if you want this can be changed to give rows numbers that match also.

Comment: `MemberQ[tabb, row]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
tabb = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {5, 4}];
row = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, 4];
```

Well, it's simply

```
 MemberQ[tabb, row]
```

returning `False` or `True` depending on randomness

Also

```
Intersection[tabb, {row}] != {}
```

Or

```
IntersectingQ[tabb, {row}]
```

Or

```
FreeQ[{}] @ UniqueElements[{tabb, {row}}]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SeedRandom[1];
tabb = RandomInteger[{0, 4}, {5, 4}]
row = {0, 3, 4, 4}

ContainsAny[tabb, {row}]
```

> True

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use `Union`:

```
table = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
row1 = {4, 5, 6};
row2 = {10, 11, 12};

SameQ[Union[#1, {#2}], #1] & @@ {table, row1}

(*True*)

SameQ[Union[#1, {#2}], #1] & @@ {table, row2}

(*False*)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
KeyExistsQ[Counts[tabb],rowThere]

KeyExistsQ[Counts[tabb],roww]

(* 
  True 
  False 
*)
```

**Data/Lists**

```
elements = {"a","k",1,"12","cdt","b","m","l","q",132,12.345,999,1000,Exp[x^2],
            Sin[y]};
tabb = Table[Take[RandomSample[elements],4],50];
roww = Take[RandomSample[elements],4];
rowThere = tabb[[-1]];
```

**Throw/Catch**

[`Do`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Do.html) loop:

```
Catch[Do[If[ContainsAll[rowThere][tabb[[i]]],Throw[True]],{i,1,Length@tabb}];
False]

(* False *)
```

```
Catch[Do[If[ContainsAll[#][tabb[[i]]],Throw[True]],{i,1,Length@tabb}];
    False]&/@{roww,rowThere}

(* {False,True} *)
```

[`Scan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scan.html)

```
Catch[Scan[If[ContainsAll[rowThere][#],Throw[True]]& , tabb];False]
Catch[Scan[If[ContainsAll[roww][#],Throw[True]]& , tabb];False]

(* 
  True
  False
*)
```